# Android Media/Photo/Files Permission when Installing the application

Tags: android, permissions

I just uploaded my SMS application on Google play store but the problem is that whenever user install the application the app needs access to Photo/Media/Files too. However i donot write this permission in my manifest. please tell me whats the issue
I write following permissions in my app:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_WAP_PUSH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_MMS"/>
```

But it still wants to access to media/photo/files
What is the issue?

Comment: That was an android studio question in which compile is used in gradle. My case is in eclipse. What to change when using eclipse? should  i need to change google play services library from eclipse?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> However i donot write this permission in my manifest.

Yes, you do:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

> What is the issue?

You are asking for a permission (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) from [the `STORAGE` permission group](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#perm-groups).